# Can I extend a bounty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In the Help section it says a bounty period is 7 days and points will be awarded based on most up voted answers.  It is a slow time of the year for gardening in the Northern hemisphere and my question [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22994/what-are-the-best-practices-for-keeping-trees-healthy-in-a-construction-area) has not received any answers that provide references.

If the bounty period could be extended to 14 days then others might participate.

Is this possible or desirable?

Comment: I have provided a referenced answer. If you count that. Finally found my source tool under a seat in one of the trucks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to extend a bounty past the initial seven days. Placing a bounty on a question is analagous to buying advertising time on TV:  you don't get a refund or extra air time if everybody is watching the Superbowl on another channel when your advertisement is aired.

After this bounty expires, you can always place another bounty on the question, though the cost will double every time you do that up to the maximum of 500 points ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/146318)).

Comment: Also good to note the 24 hour grace period if the placer of the bounty fails to award it by the end of the regular time.